# Why do tiles seems to jump around when using ArcGIS cache layer in Openlayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, arcgis-server, rest, tilecache

I am use Openlayers to add ArcGIS  tilecache layers using arcgiscache class or another way which is jsonp.

I can show the map properly, but when I pan, zoom or drag the map, the tiles seem to jump around, it does not look any good.

Can anybody give me some advice?
In **[this example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/arcgiscache_ags.html)** it has been noticed that a problem the users encounter is that the tiles seem to "jump around", but I do not know how to handle it ！

```
var markers, layer;
var features = [];
var map, baseLayer,
    layerURL = "myurl";

function init() {
    var jsonp = new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script();
    jsonp.createRequest(layerURL, {
        f: 'json',
        pretty: 'true'
    }, initMap);

}
function initMap(layerInfo) {
    baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache("arciscache", layerURL, {
        layerInfo: layerInfo
    });
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        maxExtent: baseLayer.maxExtent,
        units: baseLayer.units,
        resolutions: baseLayer.resolutions,
        numZoomLevels: baseLayer.numZoomLevels,
        tileSize: baseLayer.tileSize,
        eventListeners: { //set event handler
            "moveend": moveEvent}

        //displayProjection: baseLayer.displayProjection
    });

    var zoomControl = map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.Zoom')[0];
    map.removeControl(zoomControl);

    map.addLayers([baseLayer]);
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition());

    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation());
    map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar());
    if (!map.getCenter()) {
        map.zoomToMaxExtent();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to so? Please share your code, and let us know in detail what exactly you are experiencing.

Comment: function init() {
    var jsonp = new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script();
    jsonp.createRequest(layerURL, {
        f: 'json',
        pretty: 'true'
    }, initMap);

}
function initMap(layerInfo) {
    baseLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.ArcGISCache("基础地图", layerURL, {
        layerInfo: layerInfo
    });
    map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
        maxExtent: baseLayer.maxExtent,
        units: baseLayer.units,
        resolutions: baseLayer.resolutions,
        numZoomLevels: baseLayer.numZoomLevels,
        tileSize: baseLayer.tileSize
    });

Comment: Can you transfer your code to your original question, please?  The edit button will let you do that and then there is a code button to format it.

Comment: @ethelhao: If you compare your code to the code given at : http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/arcgiscache_ags.html You'll notice that you are initilising the map differently, than given on that page. You are not setting the StartBounds, units, and tileSize correctly.

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe,thanks for your reply,I'll check it now

Comment: @Devdatta but i use the way of jsonp to dynamicly read layerinfo ,so StartBounds, units, and tileSize should not go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and solved it as follows:

```
var mapRestrictedExtent = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
  layerInfo.initialExtent.xmin,
  layerInfo.initialExtent.ymin,
  layerInfo.initialExtent.xmax,
  layerInfo.initialExtent.ymax
);

map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
  //...
  restrictedExtent: mapRestrictedExtent,
  //...
});
```

Source (mostly): http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/openlayers-users/2011-August/021992.html